# Can not get tweets on my twitter account using third party API in Iphone app

Tags: ios, image, post, twitter

```
-(IBAction)btnPostclick
{NSURL *url = [NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://yfrog . com/api/uploadAndPost"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setDelegate:self];
if (IMG)
{
if([galleryImageView.image description] == NULL)
{
[request setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"], 0.8)     forKey:@"media"];
}
else
{
[request setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(galleryImageView.image, 0.8) forKey:@"media"];
}
}
else
{
[request setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"], 0.8) forKey:@"media"];            
}        
[request setPostValue:userdata.twitterUserName forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:userdata.twitterPassword forKey:@"password"];
[request setPostValue:comm forKey:@"message"];
[request startAsynchronous];        
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];}
```

I'm using yfrog API to share image and tweets.

I call the above API using `ASIFormDataRequest`. I have set my twitter username & password in request. The request is called asynchronously.

When response arrives `-(void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request` method get called automatically.
I get successful response in

```
-(void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"Response -> %@",response);
}
```

But it does not send tweets on my twitter account.
Can anyone solve this issue?

Base SDK for app is: `iOS 4.3`

Deployment Target for app is: `3.1.3`